# Is it always a sin to make weapons?

Tags: mahabharata, weapon, sin, kshatriya

In the Anushasana Parva of the Mahabharata, just like in the Shanti Parva, Bhishma gives advice to Yudishthira and concerning how to be a good king and how to be good person, while he is lying on a bed of arrows after the end of the Kurukshetra war.  In [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a023.htm), Bhishma tells Yudhishthira about various actions which are rewarded and punished in the afterlife.  One part of the list seems rather peculiar to me, though:

> śastravikrayakāś caiva kartāraś ca yudhiṣṭhira 
>  
>   śalyānāṃ dhanuṣāṃ caiva te vai nirayagāminaḥ
>
> They who sell weapons, they who forge weapons, they who make shafts, and they who make bows, have to sink in hell.

So my question is, is it always a sin to make weapons?

Is the verse just saying that people shouldn't go into a weapons-making as a business?  Or is it actually saying that it is forbidden for anyone to make a weapon under any circumstances? It would be rather strange if making weapons is categorically forbidden; how in the world would Kshatriyas get the weapons they need then?

Do the Manu Smriti or other Dharma Shastras shed any light on this?

Comment: I think if its a king or govt. funded thing, then its okay because you are serving the nation or the king, going into it as a business does raise the question of morality.

Comment: @AmitSaxena Yeah, that was my thought as well, but then why would selling weapons and making them be listed as separate sins?  So I'd like to find some scripture that clarifies whether people who work for the king can make weapons for him.

Comment: Could be an [interpolation](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41694638?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)?

Comment: @sv. Well, it's a possibility, but most of the other sins described in the chapter are mentioned in the Manu Smriti and other Dharma Shastras, so I think it is authentic.

Comment: At least we can say that a similar verse can be found in other scriptures, see eg The Vishnu Purana: Book II: Chapter VI at http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp064.htm "The maker of arrows is sentenced to the Vedhaka (piercing) hell: and the maker of lances, swords, and other weapons, to the dreadful hell called Viśasana (murderous)."

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Thanks, I didn't know that.  I still think it may mean "maker of weapons as a business".

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think that verses such as these apply to persons who are not souls surrendered to Lord Krishna, they do not know the doctrine of the self and devotion (bhakti) to Krishna as the ultimate goal or aim of life, and thus being ignorants if they are makers of weapons they are sentenced to hell. On the other hand those who are souls surrendered to Krishna, and live a life of devotion to Him, even if they are manufacturers of weapons, will not be subject to the influence of karma and hell. Is not that the point of the teaching of the Bhagavad Gita?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Yes, of course if you perform Sharanagati then you'll get Moksha no matter what you do.  I'm just interested in questions like this out of intellectual curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

I have searched Parashara,Vashishta and Yajnavalkya Smritis for relevant verses.Unable to find any.

The Manu smriti ,however,has a verse which says that the maker of bows and arrows are to be avoided(as sinners).

> 3.160. A maker of bows and of arrows, he who lasciviously dallies with a brother’s widow, the betrayer of a friend, one who subsists by
>   gambling, he who learns (the Veda) from his son,

[image]

> are to be carefully avoided

.This chapter gives long lists of persons who are to be avoided and the makers of bows and arrows are one of them.

I was looking for more verses that talk about the makers of weapons to be used in wars but unable to find any.In the case of a war ,i presume,it is a duty of the weapon maker to craft arms to be used by soldiers & hence it(the act of making weapons) might not incur any sin then.